# How to build Yasuo appropriately

Tags: league-of-legends

I have a little problem about how to build Yasuo. With my current item build, I reach ~90% critical chance. But of course it would obviously be better to reach the 100% mark.

Current Runes are 5xCrit Marks, 4xAD Marks, 9xScaling Health Seals, 9xMR Glyphs, 3xAD Essences.

My current item build: Doran's Blade, Statikks, Berserker Greaves, IE, BT, LW and one defense item like Randuins, Banshee's or GA.

My problem is that Yasuo has just 80% critical strike with this build. With my 5% critical chance from runes I come up to 90%.

Is that already enough? Or should I change LW for Trinity Force? Or better change Statikks for Phantom Dancer?

Comment: 90% crit is plenty from my experience

Comment: PD > SS in late game.

Comment: possible dublicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/183046/what-items-should-i-get-for-a-yasuo-top and maybe bit too broad

Comment: If you would read both questions not just superficial it would be clear that the questions have two different intensions ...

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe reaching 100% crit is a good idea. Instead, I would improve my damage or my survivability. First of all, when you build a champion, you should consider who are you against. Static builds are terrible, your build should adapt to each game depending on who are you against and how is the lane going.

Anyway, if we talk about END GAME build, consider items that are a MUST for an ad assassin:
Infinity Edge, Last Wisper.

You already have 40% crit, and your crit deals 250% damage. You can now get a Static Shiv or a Youmuu's Ghostblade, reaching 80% crit with a Static or 70% with a Youmuu ONLY WITH ITEMS + PASSIVE.

At this point I would stop building crit, and I wouldn't also wasting runes slot to increase it, instead I prefer scaling damage or armor penetration runes. Yes, yasuo passive is OP, but you should consider that reaching 100% crit is pointless because you should consider your average damage output and improving your attack speed and / or damage is more rewarding.

At this point you should have:
**Infinity**, **LW**, **Boots and Static**.

You should get one defensive item (GA is usually preferred) or Mercurial Scimitar (nice if they have strong CC, but has also noticeable damage) and if you like life steal Blade of the Ruined King or Ravenous Hydra.

**Final Build:**
**Infinity**, **LW**, **Boots** (attack speed), **Static**, **Ravenous Hydra** and **GA**.

Now you have:

+195 dmg
+80% crit
+12% life steal
+65% attack speed
+35% armor ignore
+6% speed
+50 armor
+50 magic resistance

Comment: I agree with this, increasing your crit chance to 100% would increase your damage output by 6.3% (2500% AD per 10 hits, rather than 2350%), or 5% (2000% per 10, rather than 1900%) without an Infinity Edge. Buying Damage or Armor Pen would increase your total damage by far more than 6% overall, because even though that last one hit is only doing 100% damage, the other 9 crits will more than make up for it.